# How to maintain back stack flow in the fragment with enabled tabs?

Tags: android-fragments

I am trying to handle the back stack of the fragment via fragment activity but it exit the application as i press default back button.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain fragment in stack , you have to set

```
fragmentTransation.add(new_fragment)
```

in the place of  fragmentTransation.replace(new_fragment) and `fragmentTransation.addToBackStack("anyReferalString")`
and in back press of mainactivity you can get the last and current fragment.